# My question disappeared - was it deleted or is this just a bug?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Some months ago I asked a question about a movie which I was struggling to identify for several years. Today I've discovered that my question is not there:
[image]

However, as you see, this question received at least 10 votes which left me wondering, if it was deleted, what is the reason. I did read the [page devoted to deletion](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions), and found no possible reasons. Can this be just a bug?

Comment: As to the [help center](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *"Identification questions that stay [inactive for 30 days and without any upvoted or accepted answer](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1417/49) are liable to be deleted."*

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, thank you, it is clear now!

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Is there really a justification for deleting an ID question that has 10 upvotes?

Comment: @Catija Well, that's to be discussed in a corresponding policy discussion, I guess.